# Export PowerPoint slides to Word without using "handouts"?

Tags: microsoft-word, microsoft-powerpoint, microsoft-word-2013, microsoft-powerpoint-2013

I have already read many other articles about converting/exporting, but they all use Handouts.

Is there a way to export the content of the slides to Word so that the occupy full pages?

Comment: What's wrong with just using the Handout functionality exactly?

Comment: Can you say why you want to do this? Why not just leave them as a powerpoint if you are going to have them full screen. If it is because recipients don't have PP, I recommend using PDF instead.

Comment: Basically I want to print them, but I need to modify with some Word functions (Header and Footer, Table of Contents... for example)

Comment: @DatVM the notes master feature in PowerPoint allows you to modify the headers and footers.  Be sure to reset the notes page to see the changes.